# is there supposed to be a default folder in sites/default?

Tags: subsites

Just noticed I have a default folder in my sites/default folder so that I have sites/default/files and sites/default/default/files

Found out-
The node with audio file upload is HIDING the file as protection from third party download.That is why only occurring with that particular content type.

Comment: Have you configure `multisite` feature in your Drupal site?

Comment: yes it is a multi-site

Comment: I know what has happened now. The node with audio file upload is HIDING the file as protection from third party download.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by 'supposed to'.

Drupal core doesn't place that folder there, no. But that doesn't mean that someone/something else hasn't. You'd have to give us that information, we couldn't possibly know.

What I will say is that no module should be writing to that path unless you've explicitly told it to, and if you have your permissions set up correctly, then the web server won't have been responsible for creating the folder.

Again, though, impossible to say from here.

Comment: I know what has happened now. The node with audio file upload is HIDING the file as protection from third party download.

Answer (score 2):

A sites/default/default/* structure is certainly a-typical of a standard install.

A possible source for this odd behavior is accidentally configuring your Drupal installation's public or private files directories that way.

It's not necessarily wrong, but it could be an indicator of misbehaving modules.  If module code introduced the extra default directory it could be possible the same module is ignoring other expected/appropriate methods to handle files.

Comment: I know what has happened now. The node with audio file upload is HIDING the file as protection from third party download.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll have to take a look at that module and see what they're doing.  Seems like an unusual approach.